# ServiceStack not URL decoding route parameter in RESTful route

Tags: urlencode, servicestack

I'm using self hosted ServiceStack to provide an API to integrate with a ticketing system, and have defined the following routes:

```
Routes
    .Add<TicketsWithStatus>("tickets/{Status}")
    .Add<TicketStatusCounts>("tickets");
```

I'm having URL encoding problems with the first route when the status contains a space.  If I browse to `http://myservicebase/json/syncreply/TicketsWithStatus?Status=On%20Hold` I get the response I'm expecting.  However, if I use the RESTful route `http://mysevicebase/tickets/On%20Hold` I don't get any results.

Debugging my application, I can see that the `On%20Hold` is being URL decoded to `On Hold` in the case of the `json/syncreply` call, but is not decoded when using the RESTful route.

How can I ensure that the status property is properly decoded when calling my service via the RESTful route?

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack doesn't UrlDecode the PathInfo, it uses the same `HttpRequest.PathInfo` that the ASP.NET Request object returns. You might have better success if you change it to **On+Hold**.

Comment: On+Hold comes through in the request DTO as "On+Hold". Feels hacky to do a HttpUtility.UrlDecode(request.Status) because the json/syncreply seems to do a UrlDecode, and I risk double decoding it. If there was consistency across both URLs then I could understand it. Not sure what to do for the best! Is there a method to determine whether a web service was called via a RESTful route, and I could to a decode only in that case?

Comment: you can just look at the Request object, e.g. `base.Request.PathInfo`

Comment: Right, thanks. Now I'm doing a check inside my service so that if base.Request.PathInfo.ToLower().StartsWith("/tickets/") then I do a UrlDecode(request.Status). It works for me, so that's great.
HOWEVER ... do you think that ServiceStack *should* UrlDecode route parameters to give a consistent experience across the REST and json/syncreply calls?